# How to count occurrences of dates in an array of date ranges: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, count

I have a date-range of 01-01-2020 to 31-12-2020 and an array of date-ranges. I want the occurrence of each date in the array vs the main range.

```
Eg: mainRange = [01-01-2020, 31-12-2020] //range is 366 days

dateRanges =[
  [01-01-2020, 03-01-2020],
  [03-01-2020, 04-01-2020],
  [03-01-2020, 06-01-2020]
];

the output should be =>

countArr = [1,1,3,2,1,1,0,0,......,0]; //array length 366
```

I am not getting how to achieve this in javascript and I am stuck.
I have tried to search a lot but I am only finding solutions in excel formulae.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Your expected output does not match your example data.   should be 1,0,3,1,0,1,0,0...

Comment: @BrianPatterson 02-01-2020 occurs in dateRanges[0]. that's why it's not 0. Check for occurrences in all the ranges. Thanks

Comment: Aaaaah, I gotcha!  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var range1 = new Date(2020, 0, 1),
    range2 = new Date(2020, 11, 31),
    dateRanges =[
        [new Date(2020, 0, 1), new Date(2020, 0, 3)],
        [new Date(2020, 0, 3), new Date(2020, 0, 4)],
        [new Date(2020, 0, 3), new Date(2020, 0, 6)],
    ],
    result = [];

while (range1 <= range2) {
    var count = 0;
    dateRanges.forEach(
        function(range) {
            if (range1 >= range[0] && range1 <= range[1]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    );
    result.push(count);
    range1.setDate(range1.getDate() + 1); //+1 day
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution worked. Sorry for the delay 

Answer (score 1):

The following will work for you

```js
let dateRanges = [
  ['01-01-2020', '03-01-2020'],
  ['03-01-2020', '04-01-2020'],
  ['03-01-2020', '06-01-2020']
];
var result = {};
dateRanges.forEach(element => {
  result[element[0]] = result[element[0]] === undefined ? 1 :result[element[0]] + 1 
  result[element[1]] = result[element[1]] === undefined ? 1 :result[element[1]] + 1 
  })
console.log(result);
```

Few notes:

1. The dates are strings and not as you wrote
2. result contains only dates that occurr at least once, so all others are zero:

```
{
  01-01-2020: 1,
  03-01-2020: 3,
  04-01-2020: 1,
  06-01-2020: 1
}
```

[See running code](https://jsfiddle.net/g8o5pdy9/)

Comment: If you wish to post running code, please do it here as a runnable snippet. It's the `<>` icon in the editor. Also, a good answer should explain how the code works. In this case, likely [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is likely a better option as it creates the result object and returns it in one go.

Comment: Could you alter it to show all the dates in the main range and the count beside? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `reduce()` to do that:

```js
let dateRanges = [ ['01-01-2020', '03-01-2020'], ['03-01-2020', '04-01-2020'], ['03-01-2020', '06-01-2020']];

datesArray=(generateDatesArray = (start, end)=>{
  for(var arr=[],dt=new Date(start); dt<=end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)){
     arr.push(new Date(dt).toLocaleDateString());
   }
   return arr;
})(new Date('2020-01-01'),new Date('2020-12-31'));

let dateObj = dateRanges.reduce((acc, dt)=>{
   strtDate = new Date(dt[0].replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, '$2-$1'));
   endDate = new Date(dt[1].replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, '$2-$1'));
   dateDiff = Math.ceil(Math.abs(strtDate-endDate)/(1000*60*60*24))+1;
   while(dateDiff--){
  acc[strtDate.toLocaleDateString()] = acc[strtDate.toLocaleDateString()] || 0;
  acc[strtDate.toLocaleDateString()]++;
  let getDt = strtDate.getDate()+1;
  strtDate.setDate(getDt);
 }
  return acc;
},{});

var result1 = datesArray.map(k=>dateObj[k] || 0);
var result2 = datesArray.map(k=>({[k]:dateObj[k] || 0}));
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Now we have date Object with date and its occurrences ready, you can easily fetch data from it.

Comment: Your solution is short and beautiful. Could you alter it to show all the dates in the main-range and the count beside? Thanks

Comment: @AshikPaul I have edited it my answer, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear. I am expecting 365 values in the result array. I am insisting on these many values because it is really important that I have to show 0's in the graph where dates are not included. If you need further clarifications let me know. Thank you so much.